# Metaclasses in python == interfaces in java?

Tags: java, python

I read that "A metaclass is the class of a class. Like a class defines how an instance of the class behaves, a metaclass defines how a class behaves. A class is an instance of a metaclass."

I was wondering how different this is from `interface` in Java. `interface` too provides a *blueprint* for the classes to follow.

Comment: No, it is not. You might want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python.

Comment: I read just that and got confused. I wished to see how `metaclass` is different from `interface`. They both define some rules which all the classes inheriting them must follow, right ?

Comment: At a basic level metaclass is similar to the `Class` class in java... But again, Java != Python... So you cannot expect them to be exactly same...

Comment: Abstract base classes are the similar concept to Java's interfaces. Metaclasses are totally different things.

Answer (score 4):

No.

**About Python Metaclass:**
Metaclass in Python **is** a class which is used to create classes. A class that you create in Python is simply an instance of its metaclass. `type` is the super most metaclass in Python.

In Python, a class is modeled as an object, which gives you a lot of flexibility in its usage, by attaching all the properties of objects to classes. For example, you can even create class definition dynamically, just the way you would create an instance of a class.
[This is a good read.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)

**About Interfaces in Java:**
First of all, an `interface` **is not** a `class`. It is just another `type` (Both interfaces and classes are types in Java). It is true that classes and interfaces are closely related in Java (An interface is a blueprint of a class). But they are entirely different types. Interface in java is simply a mechanism to achieve abstraction.

**Conclusion:** In Python, you really don't have anything like `java interface`.

Comment: Python has multiple inheritance, so interface is not necessary, instead mixin can be used